# Prove g(x) is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question in my class
If $g$ is an entire function and
 $g(z)=g(z+z')$ for all $z\in C$ and $z'=a+bi,a,b\in Z$. How to prove g is constant

Comment: What about $g(z)=e^{2 \pi z}$, this is invariant under $z \mapsto z+i$.

Comment: Unless you mean for all $z'$.

Comment: @DylanYott yes,,

Comment: Find a compact subset $F$ of the plane such that $g$ attains all of its values already in $F$. Conclude that $g$ is a bounded entire function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you mean for all $z' \in \Bbb Z[i]$, in which case $g$ is an elliptic function. It is clear that $g$ is determined by its values on the unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, since any point can be translated into this square by an element of $\Bbb Z[i]$. Since $g(z\pm i)=g(z \pm 1)= g(z)$, we see that $g$ takes on identical values on opposite points of the unit square. Thus, $g$ gives a well defined continuous function on the torus $T$ you get by identifying opposite sides of this square. Since $T$ is compact, $g(T)$ is bounded, so $g(\Bbb C)= g(T)$ is a bounded subset of $\Bbb C$. Since $g$ is bounded and entire it is constant by Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $z'$ is fixed, then the proposition is false as it has been pointed out in the comments $$\rm e ^{2\pi z} \ \ \ \ is \ invariant\ under\ z\rightarrow z+i  $$

If you mean $z'$ is arbitrary, then fix $z=0$, which yields $g(0)=g(z'), \forall z' \in \mathbb C$

Comment: I think he means that $z' \in \Bbb Z[i]$, whereas with this derivative argument I think you're assuming $z' \in \Bbb C$ is arbitrary. If $z'$ is allowed to be arbitrary, you could just say $g(0)=g(z')$ for any $z'$, so $g$ would surely be constant. Note, this doesn't even use any differentiability assumption on $g$.